# Making 'id' attr_accessible/mass-assignable (and all other attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to import existing data into my database, which already has `id` values. However, AR won't let me mass-assign `id`s.

I can

```
class User
  attr_accessible :id
```

But then, all other attributes aren't. I've also tried

```
class User
  attr_protected #none
```

To no effect. How do I make `id` mass-assignable?

** I want my column to be named `id`. I don't want two sets of ids for the same data.

Comment: Does setting it normally (`user.id = 42`) work as expected?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes, I was just hoping for a simple one-liner like `User.create( :id => 42, :name => 'Boo')`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord won't allow you to set ids for records, cause id is the primary key.

You can use [taps](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps) gem for importing/exporting data thought. It's very easy to use and was build exactly for this purposes.

Comment: Actually, I have found that ActiveRecord will let me overwrite and save an arbitrary value for the primary key (Rails 2.3.5, at least), but I have yet to find how to mass assign it. Andrew Marshall's comment above corroborates this.

Answer (score 0):

For the safety reasons, I would suggest NOT to make `id` as `attribute_accessible`. You can try the following,

```
user = User.find_or_create_by_id("100")
user.update_attributes({:artists_name => "jake", :age => 10})
```

Comment: What are those safety reasons? They are most likely not applicable to my case.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a pain, depending on how many attributes you have, but I think you need to explicitly set all of the attributes to `attr_accessible`

ie.

```
class User
  attr_accessible :id, :name # etc.
```